# DirectX11 Radix Sort

Tags: sorting, hlsl, radix-sort, directcompute

I'm struggling to implement an efficient Radix Sort in DirectX11.
I need to quickly sort no more than 256K items.
It doesn't need to be in-place.
Using CUDA / OpenCL is not an option.

I have it almost working, but it has a few problems:

- The histogram generation is quite fast, but still takes much longer than quoted figures online
- On subsequent sort passes, the order of keys whose lower bits are identical, is not preserved, due to the InterlockedAdd on the histogram buffer in cp_sort (see below)
- cp_sort is **really** slow, due to global memory access on that same InterlockedAdd

I've been trying to understand how I can fix this, based on algorithms online, but I can't seem to understand them.

Here are my 3 kernels. (it's for a billboarded particle system, so the term 'quad' just refers to an item to be sorted)

```
// 8 bits per radix
#define NUM_RADIXES 4
#define RADIX_SIZE 256

// buffers
StructuredBuffer<Quad>   g_particleQuadBuffer   : register( t20 );
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> g_indexBuffer          : register( u0 );
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> g_histogram            : register( u1 );
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> g_indexOutBuffer       : register( u2 );


// quad buffer counter
cbuffer BufferCounter : register( b12 )
{
    uint numQuads;
    uint pad[ 3 ];
}


// on-chip memory for fast histogram calculation
#define SHARED_MEM_PADDING 8 // to try and reduce bank conflicts
groupshared uint g_localHistogram[ NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ];


// convert a float to a sortable int, assuming all inputs are negative
uint floatToUInt( float input )
{
    return 0xffffffff - asuint( input );
}


// initialise the indices, and build the histograms (dispatched with numQuads / ( NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE ))
[numthreads( NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE, 1, 1 )]
void cp_histogram( uint3 groupID : SV_GroupID, uint groupIndex : SV_GroupIndex )
{
    // initialise local histogram
    g_localHistogram[ groupIndex * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ] = 0;
    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();

    // check within range
    uint quadIndex = ( groupID.x * NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE ) + groupIndex;
    if ( quadIndex < numQuads )
    {
        // initialise index
        g_indexBuffer[ quadIndex ] = quadIndex;

        // floating point to sortable uint
        uint value = floatToUInt( g_particleQuadBuffer[ quadIndex ].v[ 0 ].projected.z );

        // build 8-bit histograms
        uint value0 = ( value       ) & 0xff;
        uint value1 = ( value >> 8  ) & 0xff;
        uint value2 = ( value >> 16 ) & 0xff;
        uint value3 = ( value >> 24 );

        InterlockedAdd( g_localHistogram[ ( value0       ) * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ], 1 );
        InterlockedAdd( g_localHistogram[ ( value1 + 256 ) * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ], 1 );
        InterlockedAdd( g_localHistogram[ ( value2 + 512 ) * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ], 1 );
        InterlockedAdd( g_localHistogram[ ( value3 + 768 ) * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ], 1 );
    }

    // write back to histogram
    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
    InterlockedAdd( g_histogram[ groupIndex ], g_localHistogram[ groupIndex * SHARED_MEM_PADDING ] );
}


// build the offsets based on histograms (dispatched with 1)
// NOTE: I know this could be more efficient, but from my profiling, its time is negligible compared to the other 2 stages, and I can optimise this separately using a parallel prefix sum if I need to
[numthreads( NUM_RADIXES, 1, 1 )]
void cp_offsets( uint groupIndex : SV_GroupIndex )
{
    uint sum = 0;
    uint base = ( groupIndex * RADIX_SIZE );
    for ( uint i = 0; i < RADIX_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        uint tempSum = g_histogram[ base + i ] + sum;
        g_histogram[ base + i ] = sum;
        sum = tempSum;
    }
}


// move the data (dispatched with numQuads / ( NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE ))
uint currentRadix;
[numthreads( NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE, 1, 1 )]
void cp_sort( uint3 groupID : SV_GroupID, uint groupIndex : SV_GroupIndex )
{
    // check within range
    uint quadIndex = ( groupID.x * NUM_RADIXES * RADIX_SIZE ) + groupIndex;
    if ( quadIndex < numQuads )
    {
        uint fi = g_indexBuffer[ quadIndex ];
        uint depth = floatToUInt( g_particleQuadBuffer[ fi ].v[ 0 ].projected.z );

        uint radix = currentRadix;

        uint pos = ( depth >> ( radix * 8 ) ) & 0xff;

        uint writePosition;
        InterlockedAdd( g_histogram[ radix * RADIX_SIZE + pos ], 1, writePosition );
        g_indexOutBuffer[ writePosition ] = fi;
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer any help on how to fix/optimise this?
I'd love to understand what some of the more complex algorithms for GPU Radix sorting are actually doing!

Thanks!